# Docker: speed up SBT image. (Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.2.6 (this may take some time)...)

Tags: docker, sbt

I use [hseeberger/scala-sbt](https://github.com/hseeberger/scala-sbt) Docker image.

When I run this image like:

```
docker run -it \
       -v `pwd`:/root \
              hseeberger/scala-sbt sbt test
```

It takes a long time for this:

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.2.6  (this may take some time)...
```

What I don't understand is that this image already defines that the SBT-Version is 1.2.6 as well as my project does?

Comment: Without having a closer look. `docker diff` might give you a hint what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you `sbt` is being lazy, and will actually download some of the jars only when it needs them (when sbt is first run).

If you want to speed it up. You can use this image as a base image in your Dockerfile (`FROM hseeberger/scala-sbt`) and run `sbt test` once without a test project, so it download the JARs.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna stick on sbt 1.2.6 you can just use the latest version `hseeberger/scala-sbt` which is `11.0.1_2.12.7_1.2.6`.

```
docker pull hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.1_2.12.7_1.2.6
```

The version number contains of the openjdk version (11.0.1), the scala version (2.12.7) and the sbt version (1.2.6). If that's all you need there is no need to reinvent the wheel :-D